# I have an ExpansionTile in flutter. I want to remove the subtitle section on expand

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I try to add code in onExpansionChanged() to set the state it does not accept find the setState() function.

```
 @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: usa.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i){
        UserActivity ua = usa[i];
        return Card(child:
            ExpansionTile(
              title:Text('Hari'),
              subtitle: Text(titleStr),
              leading:Image.network(imgUrl,),
              initiallyExpanded: false,
              onExpansionChanged: (bool) {
                titleStr='';
              },
              children:[
                Text("Heloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"),
              ]


            )
        );
```

Comment: it does not accept find the setState() function? It's your ExpansionTile inside a StatefulWidget?

Comment: Can you post full class in the question? Ideally you can only use setState() function inside of a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I am trying to implement the buildSuggestion of SearchDelegate and I am using ExpansionTile. When I click on a result I want the subtitle to be removed and ti will be rendered in children widget.